# Searching from MySql database and display the results as a hyperlink

Tags: php

Here is my code, what I want to do is display the first names of my friends in another page as Hyperlinks and when a link is clicked I want to display the data.

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","abc123","my_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM friends");



while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{

echo "<p>" . $row['FirstName'] . "</p>";
echo "<p>" . $row['LastName'] . "</p>";
echo "<p>" . $row['Email'] . "</p>";
echo "<p>" . $row['Address'] . "</p>";
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: We are here to help you, not to do you work. Have you tried anything yet?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","abc123","my_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM friends");



while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{?>php

<a href=<?php "echo "<p>" . $row['FirstName'] . "</p>";"?>> `your page name`</a><?php
echo "<p>" . $row['LastName'] . "</p>";
echo "<p>" . $row['Email'] . "</p>";
echo "<p>" . $row['Address'] . "</p>";
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your file from questions change:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{

echo "<p>" . $row['FirstName'] . "</p>";
echo "<p>" . $row['LastName'] . "</p>";
echo "<p>" . $row['Email'] . "</p>";
echo "<p>" . $row['Address'] . "</p>";
}
```

to

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo '<a href="show.php?UserId='.$row['UserId'].'"> . $row['FirstName'] . "</a>";
}
```

show.php

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","abc123","my_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
if(isset($_GET['UserId'])){
if(is_numeric($_GET['UserId'])){
$UserId = (int)$_GET['UserId'];

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM friends WHERE UserId= $UserId");
if(count($result)){
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{

echo "<p>" . $row['FirstName'] . "</p>";
echo "<p>" . $row['LastName'] . "</p>";
echo "<p>" . $row['Email'] . "</p>";
echo "<p>" . $row['Address'] . "</p>";
}}}}
```

**Important: I'm not sure what is UserId column name, so change it.**

*Also, please check for syntax errors.*

Answer (score 0):

Try connection it with an incremental ID out of the database. So every row in your friends table must have a unique ID. In that way you can connect it and get the row data from your friends table.

So your friends table must look like this:

```
friend_id (unique id)
firstname
lastname
email
address
```

And your code can be something like (this is not save from any attacks):

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","abc123","my_db");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
   echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

if(isset($_GET['friendid'])) { 
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM friends");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
       echo "<p>" . $row['FirstName'] . "</p>";
       echo "<p>" . $row['LastName'] . "</p>";
       echo "<p>" . $row['Email'] . "</p>";
       echo "<p>" . $row['Address'] . "</p>";
       echo "<p><a href=\"_YOUR_SCRIPT_URL_HERE_?friendid=".$row['friend_id']."\" target=\"_self\">Details</a></p>";
    }
} else {
   $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM friends WHERE friend_id = '".$_GET['friendid']."'");
   $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);  
   echo "<p>" . $row['FirstName'] . "</p>";
   echo "<p>" . $row['LastName'] . "</p>";
   echo "<p>" . $row['Email'] . "</p>";
   echo "<p>" . $row['Address'] . "</p>";  
} 
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```